# Why is it not advised to connect DC parallel converters directly

Tags: dc-dc-converter

This is what I found in DC-DC converter website:

> DC-DC Converter can be connected in parallel, however, the output
> wires should be separate all the way to the battery or load, and be
> the same lengths. DO NOT join the 'big' output negative and positive
> together and then run a thick 2 AWG cable to the load. Instead, run
> two separate sets of smaller 6 AWG cables to the load, and the output
> currents should stay pretty close to equal

Why? Shouldn't it result in same output currents?

Comment: No device is identical and it can interfere with the control loops.

Comment: What DC-DC converter ? Reference to component please. The AWG wiring you make reference to are high-current which implies converters of medium to high power. More info about the converters is required ...

Comment: Which website says that? How can you trust what it says? Why would there even be need to connect DC/DC converter outputs together? What is the application? Unless a manual says two outputs can be connected together, they usually can't and will lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. As Mike says, no two devices are identical, are in identical housing and get thus equally hot etc. If one controller decides the target voltage is higher than the other, then that controller will have to provide practically all of the load. Not what you wanted to do when you used two of them in parallel.
2. These are dynamic control systems, with a output ripple at frequencies at which their control loops resonate, and at the switching frequency, which is often fixed (but that also depends on the controller architecture). That's kind of inherent. Given external load, this can mean that the ripple "dips" of one controller make the other overcompensate, which makes the first one dip, and so on - you can build an oscillator of potentially unforeseen frequency that way, when you actually wanted a stable output voltage.
    You need to either significantly dampen the system output¹ of each controller, which might run afoul of regulation in the first place, or you might need to synchronize both controllers and make them observe the same thing. Whether you can choose one of these two routes depends on your application and/or your controller architecture. In general, neither works.

---

¹ dampening can be achieved through series resistance, just as Simon B. pointed out in his answer - but note that output resistance means that the output voltage fluctuates with load current - kind of the opposite of what you buy a voltage *regulator* for!

Answer (score 1):

The resistance of the wires matters.

No two DC/DC converters will put out exactly the same voltage. If you connect them directly to each other, then the one with the higher voltage will take all the load, up to the point where it hits its current limit and shuts down.

If you connect them separately, then the small resistance of each wire will produce a small voltage drop, proportional to the current through that wire. The currents will tend to even out across them.